# How do I propagate errors back to the previous layers for convolutional neural network?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, machine-learning, convolution

I'm trying to figure out the backward propagation for convolutional neural network.

I drew the following figure to illustrate the forward propagation of a 3-layer model. Someone may argue the flatten should be counted as another layer, well, that would make me write a few more lines of derivation without giving any good.

[image]

To simplify the whole process, I decided to consider binary classification and just one training example which is also an input image, so the output of the 1st layer would be

$a^{[1]} = ReLU (x * w^{[1]} + b^{[1]}) \tag{1}$

where the $*$ denotes the convolution operation, $w^{[1]}$ denotes the kernel/filter used in this convolution operation, $b^{[1]}$ denotes the bias/intercept for layer`[1]`.

Given the input image $x$ is size of (8, 8), the filter size of (3, 3), so the output of layer`[1]` $a^{[1]}$ is size of (6, 6).

$m$ denotes the number of training examples, so $m=1$ here, and the last dimension of (m, 8, 8, 1) means the color channel which is also 1 here.

There are 10 learnable params in layer`[1]`, 9 for the kernel, 1 for the bias and the activation function is ReLU in this model.

There is no learnable params or activation function in layer`[2]` though, I still use $a$ to denote the output of this layer. So $a^{[2]}$ is size of (3, 3), as the kernel size = (2, 2).

$a^{[3]}$ denotes the output of the last layer of the model and could be computed using this formula

$a^{[3]} = \sigma{(z^{[3]})} \tag{2}$

where $\sigma{(\cdot)}$ denotes the sigmoid function and $z^{[3]} = a^{[2]} \cdot w^{[3]} + b^{[3]} \tag{3}$

so, there are another 10 params to learn, 9 for $w^{[3]}$ and 1 for $b^{[3]}$.

the loss function could be

$$ \mathcal{L}(a^{[3]}, y) =  - [y \log a^{[3]} + (1-y)  \log(1-a^{[3]})] \tag{4}$$

I clearly understand part of the backward propagation for this model, which is

$$
\dfrac{d\mathcal{L}(a^{[3]}, y)}{da^{[3]}} = -\dfrac{y}{a^{[3]}} + \dfrac{1-y}{1-a^{[3]}} \tag{5}
$$

$$
\dfrac{da^{[3]}}{dz^{[3]}} = a^{[3]}\,(1-a^{[3]}) \tag{6}
$$

\begin{align}
\frac{d\mathcal{L}(a^{[3]}, y)}{dz^{[3]}}
= a^{[3]} - y \tag{7}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{d\mathcal{L}(a^{[3]}, y)}{da^{[2]}}
= \frac{d\mathcal{L}(a^{[3]}, y)}{dz^{[3]}} \cdot w^{[3]T}
\tag{8}
\end{align}

the part of equation (3) could be rewritten as

$
a^{[2]} \cdot w^{[3]} 
= a^{[2]}_{1,1} \ w^{[3]}_{1} + a^{[2]}_{1,2} \ w^{[3]}_{2}+ a^{[2]}_{1,3} \ w^{[3]}_{3} \\
+ a^{[2]}_{2,1} \ w^{[3]}_{4} + a^{[2]}_{2,2} \ w^{[3]}_5+ a^{[2]}_{2,3} \ w^{[3]}_{6} \\
+ a^{[2]}_{3,1} \ w^{[3]}_{7} + a^{[2]}_{3,2} \ w^{[3]}_{8}+ a^{[2]}_{3,3} \ w^{[3]}_{9} \tag{9}
$

where
$
a^{[2]}_{1,1} = \max(a^{[1]}_{1,1}, a^{[1]}_{1,2}, a^{[1]}_{2,1}, a^{[1]}_{2,2}) \tag{10}
$

$
a^{[2]}_{p,r} = \max(a^{[1]}_{2p-1,2r-1}, a^{[1]}_{2p-1,2r}, a^{[1]}_{2p,2r-1}, a^{[1]}_{2p,2r}) \tag{11}
$

How do I propagate errors back to layer`[2]` and `[1]`?

I'm now blocked at the step of propagating errors from $a^{[2]}$ to $a^{[1]}$.

If $a^{[1]}_{1,1}$ is the output of equation (10), is it correct to use the formula below to compute $
\dfrac{d\mathcal{L}(a^{[3]}, y)}{da^{[1]}}
$?

$
\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}(a^{[3]}, y)}{\partial a^{[1]}_{1,1}} = 
\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}(a^{[3]}, y)}{\partial a^{[2]}_{1,1}} =
\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}(a^{[3]}, y)}{\partial z^{[3]}} \ w^{[3]}_1 = (a^{[3]} - y)\ w^{[3]}_1
$

If yes, what about the other 3 guys?

I went through [a post for this](https://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/machine-learning/convolutional-neural-networks/) though, I still don't know what should I do to complete the formulas after (8). Could someone give me a hint?

Note: I know what the convolution operation and cross-correlation are in deep learning. I'd just like to know the backward propagation part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these will be helpful:

- https://cs.nju.edu.cn/wujx/paper/CNN.pdf
- http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/ConvolutionalNeuralNetwork/

Convolutional layers are pretty simple as they are basically a set of weights that are dragged across the image plane. This means you first need to figure out the gradient for a single patch of the image. And once you've done that, the gradient (with respect to the convolutional weights) will be a sum of the gradients over all patches of the image.

Comment: Thank you so much. I know the basics of pooling layer, e.g. the 2nd layer in my OP. Your link says "... some form of pooling which results in translation invariant features." what does "translation invariant features" mean?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208936/what-is-translation-invariance-in-computer-vision-and-convolutional-neural-netwo